# Function pointer allocated on the heap

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, function-pointers

I want to declare a local function pointer, allocate space for the pointer on the heap, point to different functions with it on the fly.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void fun(){
 printf("fun");
}

typedef void(*fp)();

int main(){
 fp f; //local pointer
 f = malloc(sizeof(f)); //allocate space for a pointer on the heap
 (*f) = &fun; //write the address of fun into the space allocated in heap
 (*f)(); // so that the contents in f, is the address of fun
}
```

But I get a compilation error at `(*f) = &fun;` that reads:  `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`. How should I do this correctly ?

Just so this does not look like an xy problem: I want to reproduce the exploit mentioned here: [Use after free exploit](https://sensepost.com/blog/2017/linux-heap-exploitation-intro-series-used-and-abused-use-after-free/)

Comment: There is no need to allocate anything. here. `f=fun;` will do everything needed. And to call  - `f()`.

Comment: A function pointer points into the code space, which conceptually is not the same in general as data. On some hardware (Harvard architectures) it is even physically different

Comment: `&fun` and `fun` are equivalent. You want simply `fp f = fun; f() /*call fun*/; f = lol; f() /*call lol*/;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to `*fp` because that expression has function type.

`fp` is meant to store a pointer, in this case a pointer to a function.  So you don't need to allocate anything.  Just assign the function's address:

```
fp f;
f = &fun;
(*f)();
```

Note also that an expression of function type is automatically converted to a pointer to said function, including when it is called, so this does the same:

```
fp f;
f = fun;
f();
```

EDIT:

If what you really want is to dynamically allocate space for a function pointer, then you need a pointer to function pointer to store it:

```
fp *f;                   // fp is void (*)(), so f is void(**)()
f = malloc(sizeof(*f));  // allocate space for function pointer
*f = func;
(*f)();     // func called

free(f);
fp *g;
g = malloc(sizeof(*g));   // possibly points to what f pointed to?
*g = evil_f;

(*g)();    // evil_func called
```

Note that the above invokes undefined behavior, and will only work on implementations that don't optimize away the value stored in `f` and reuses the same memory region to assign to `g`.

Comment: But isn't this a local pointer on the stack, pointing to the function ? I want it to be `malloc`ed for a reason. Is this even possible ?

Comment: @rranjik It is local, but the pointer contains a value (i.e. the address of a function) that is valid for the lifetime of the program.  So you can pass the contents of that pointer to other functions or return it from the current function and use it safely.

Comment: @rranjik, `malloc` allocates space for an *object*, and returns a pointer to that space.  There is no way to dynamically allocate space for a *function*, and no need for it, because C has no mechanism for dynamically writing function implementations.

Comment: @dbush Thank you very much!